# Do I say "I am going" or "I will be going"?

Tags: tenses, future

Which sounds more correct?

1. I am going to the post office in 2 hours
2. I will be going to the post office in 2 hours

Is there any difference between the two sentences?

Comment: A little confused as to the answer you're looking for.  I think you just said them both - are you looking for contrasting meanings, or which to use for a particular situation?

Comment: I need to correct a sentence -I will go to the post office in 2 hours. Shall I post the letter for you? Which answer should I choose. 1. I am ging to the post office in 2 hours. Shall I post the letter for you? or 2. I will be going to the post office in 2 hours. Shall I post the letter for you?

Comment: #2 - will be going - is more appropriate to speak of the future. Please post these kinds of basic English questions on our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This might be a basic Question however I had asked many English people which is the correct one and nobody could give me the right answer. Everyone would say that I can use both. So I still do not know although I am fluent in English

Comment: @user78432 Everyone would be right. You can use both. There is very little difference in meaning. The present tense can be used to denote future events in English. Both are correct.

Comment: I am reopening this and instead marking it as a duplicate of a question that explains a whole number of ways you can express future actions in. [Do have a look](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57053/differences-between-ways-to-express-future-actions). And there are more related question still linked from that one.

Comment: @RegDwigнt This is still closed and still marked as duplicate! Btw, you're right the other question is ridiculous. I'm not sure it's useful to link to it, it will just put people off *this* eminently more sensible question!

Answer (score 3):

You can use either one, but the two have (very) slightly different emphases. "I will be going" places the emphasis on the future, but gives a hazy, not-quite-here yet, and could be altered impression. Something might prevent you, after all. However "I am going" is much stronger and places the emphasis on commitment. "I am going" means that nothing will stop you from going.

Comment: Of course, if you want something even stronger you can always adopt the *"You **shall** go to the ball!"* style.

Comment: I think of the difference in feel as being between *assertion* ("I am going") and *prediction* ("I will be going"), but it can be a very slight or absent difference depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking which is correct, they both are. In this particular usage there is not much to choose between the two.

However, when we're talking about the future, the present continuous is usually used with arrangements you have already made. The continuous form with *will* is more of a prediction or factual assertion about what will be happening at a certain point in the future. The issue is a bit more complicated in your example, because you are using *GO* as the main verb. People tend to use the present continuous and the so-called *going to*  future interchangeably when the main lexical verb is *GO*.

However, just to bring out the difference between the present continuous and the continuous form with *will*, we can show that the present continuous seems to be infelicitous (wrong) for situations that you have not already arranged, but that the so-called future continuous is fine for talking about such future events:

- I'm living in abject poverty when I'm old. *
- I'll be living in poverty when I'm old.

The first sounds wrong unless actually really have plans to do so!