# I am in New York when you are in London next week

Tags: future

Is the titular sentence grammatically correct? I typically use will and I am trying to learn (and teach) better forms.

It sounds odd but if both *I* and *you* have made plans to be in New York and London respectively, it seems this is the way to state the fact?

Perhaps it is not OK to say "You are in London next week"? because it is somebody else's plan not mine, and who am I to treat is as confirmed? (well, if I were a supervisor or a military commander confirming plans for my subordinates I might need to say so.)

I already went through [these](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175262/do-i-say-i-am-going-or-i-will-be-going) [two](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57053/differences-between-ways-to-express-future-actions) questions and this question is a followup. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In conversation, I'd likely use contractions and express it as a future event— *I'll be in New York when you'll be in London next week* — but the way you have it formulated is fine, and there's nothing wrong with saying *You are in London next week* except that you'd rarely need to state someone's plans when speaking with him or her directly. It isn't very clear what your question is, I'm afraid.

Comment: @choster Thank you for the kind welcome and for the clarification. My question implicitly was whether the statement in the title is grammatically correct or not, and you did answer my question. I will .. sorry, I am going to .. err.. I am editing it in a minute to make the question explicit. ;-)  [edited; I am a computer programmer who also happens to be teaching English hence the exploration of various forms dictated by grammatical rules to verify that I understand the rules correctly]